# How are changes to `sys.modules` propagated?

Tags: python, python-module, sys

Is `sys.modules` shared by the whole Python process, so that changes in sys.modules are seen in different modules, and exec statements (even with `exec("",{},{})`)? Or are there different copies for different contexts?

Comment: You may need to be more specific about your question. Everyone sees the same `sys.modules`, but modifying `sys.modules` directly (say, replacing the cached module for one key with a different one) won't change what you see in modules that have already imported that cached module. What behaviors are you really asking about? Just `sys.modules` specifically? Or broader behaviors related to multiply importing the same module?

Comment: @ShadowRanger I guess what I'm asking is this: if I change sys.modules anywhere in the program (in a different file, in exec/eval, in a function, etc.) and another file within the same Python process imports it, will they see the changed module? That is, is the list of modules shared by everyone?

Comment: They will "see" the same dict (not a list), but it doesn't actually matter for the purpose of using the module contents. It won't even affect the *current* context.

Answer (score 0):

> Is `sys.modules` shared by the whole Python process

With caveats, yes. Every module that does `import sys` in a global scope will (unless, for some reason, it finds a *different* `sys` from the standard library module; or unless it overwrites the name `sys` with something else; or unless it `del`s the name; or...) have a global name `sys` which refers to *the same `module` object* for the `sys` module. Therefore, `sys.modules` will be the same dictionary in each case.

> so that changes in `sys.modules` are seen in different modules

Yes, **but** such changes *do not* impact on *any* module's existing imports (unless you are using `sys.modules` to access and then modify *the module object itself*; but then, you could have just as easily done that using its existing global name). They **only** impact what happens if an `import` statement is executed **after** the change (and *only if* the `import` process is not altered to prevent or modify that behaviour). The dictionary (created internally by behind-the-scenes magic, and made available as `sys.modules` via more magic, when `sys` is imported) is **just** a cache. Changes like this won't matter *even within the same* module.

Consider:

```
import sys
sys.modules['sys'] = 'hax' # does not have any impact on `sys`
sys.modules # works just fine
```

Or, a more complex example:

```
>>> def hax():
...     import sys # this is only a local name
...     sys.modules['foo'] = 'hi mom'
...     global foo # causes the name to be put in the global namespace
...     import foo # causes the cached string to be loaded as the "module"
... 
>>> hax() # "import" our fake foo module
>>> foo # it is not a module at all, but just a string
'hi mom'
>>> sys # as expected, this is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
>>> import sys # but if we import it,
>>> sys.modules['foo'] # we get the same module object, and the same dict
'hi mom'
>>> # which still contains that string
```

Notice that it is `import foo` that causes `foo` to become a global variable. We can't use `foo` simply by changing `sys.modules['foo']`, and altering the latter won't impact the former. If we continue from above:

```
>>> sys.modules['foo'] = 'hi dad' # the change is not reflected...
>>> foo
'hi mom'
>>> import foo # until we reload from the cache.
>>> foo
'hi dad'
```

> and exec statements (even with `exec("",{},{})`)?

This is completely unrelated. `exec` *doesn't care* about the contents of `sys.modules`, unless perhaps you use it to build the dict that you pass for the `globals` argument.

Comment: So, what I'm getting that if you change sys.modules["foo"], any file that later on tries to import foo will in fact see the new foo. I though that each namespace has their own module cache.

Comment: @DrownedSuccess no, there's only one module cache and it's shared everywhere.

Comment: You understand correctly. It will get the new foo from the cache, even if it has never previously imported sys or otherwise interacted with that cache. It is process-global, but it is still a cache. (and, again: it is possible to hook into the module loading process, such that the cache is bypassed, replaced etc.)

Answer (score 0):

`sys.modules` contains references to all the modules your program imports.  If you modify one of those modules directly, those changes will be reflected in every place that has imported that module, since their references are to the same module object. If you replace a module in `sys.modules` with an updated one, those changes will *not* be seen elsewhere because they still have a reference to the old module object.

It's really no different than any other dictionary.

```
d = dict()
d['a'] = 1
x = d['a']
d['a'] = 906
print(x, d['a'])
# 1 906
```